# reporting R2 score in tensorflow "regression" model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like my model to report r2 square in the validation, however I cannot find the right metric to fill in ???,

```
model.compile(loss = 'mse',
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics = '???')
```

Thanks for any hint in advance

Comment: By calculation R2 scores is R square scores but tfa.metrics.RSquare needs to use the same sizes same order of y_true and y_predict.

https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/RSquare

Answer (score 0):

my answer to the question comment is y calculation R2 scores is R square scores but tfa.metrics.RSquare needs to use the same sizes same order of y_true and y_predict [R2](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/RSquare) but you can do it for multi-classes when you need input to output as channels or discrete.

Sample: Custom multi classes, it required tf.float32 as default tf.variable assignment and return as multi-class attacks.

```
import tensorflow as tf

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MulticlassSumSquare(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='multiclass_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassSumSquare, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.value = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')
        
    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.reshape( tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=0), shape=(-1, 1))
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, 'float32')
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, 'float32')
        temp = 1 - ( ( y_pred - y_true ) / ( y_pred + y_true ) )
        self.value.assign_add( tf.reduce_sum(temp) )

    def result(self):
        return self.value

    def reset_state(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.value.assign(0.)
        
class MyDenseLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, num_outputs):
        super(MyDenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.num_outputs = num_outputs
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        min_size_init = tf.keras.initializers.Ones()
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=[int(input_shape[-1]), self.num_outputs],
        initializer = min_size_init, trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        temp = tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)       # , shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32)
        return temp
        
start = 3
limit = 33
delta = 3
sample = tf.range(start, limit, delta)
sample = tf.cast( sample, dtype=tf.float32 )
sample = tf.constant( sample, shape=( 10, 1 ) )
label = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], dtype=tf.int64)
layer = MyDenseLayer(10)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(sample, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(1, 10, 1), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(label, shape=(1, 10, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 1, 1 )),
    layer
])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
    name='Nadam'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn, metrics=[MulticlassSumSquare()])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit( dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=10000 )
```

Output: Single record R suqare no change no loss fun return value.

```
Epoch 1/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: nan - multiclass_true_positives: 7.0621
Epoch 2/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: nan - multiclass_true_positives: 7.0621
```

Sample: Discrete actions in games

```
group_2_Heriken_kick_Left = tf.constant([ 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 ], shape=(1, 1, 1, 48))
```

[image: Sample]

Comment: R^2 score is for regression, not for classification, so your whole answer about multiple classes for R^2 score makes no sense.

Comment: I example both custom matrix and Tensorflow addons, R2 scores and the answer is multiple classes that is because you cannot do it with basics R2.